# Update record after payment is made successfully through google checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-checkout

I am using google checkout HTML API with a ruby on rails application. I want to add/update records in my local database after a successful payment. I am getting Notification serial number in response on API callback URL.
My question is how can i check that payment is successfully made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sends a serial number notification for every order notification. This notification contains the serial number as a name value pair in the POST message body.

Once you've successfully received the serial number notification, you need to use the Notification History API to request the associated notification, such as the New Order Notification.

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API#requesting_notifications

Here are other types of notifications you can request:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API#Types_of_Notifications